# how to use iterator in recursive function in python?

Tags: python, variables, recursion, iterator, global

I want to convert my code such that I don't have to use an extra variable (i.e, s in the example below). I know that there is a way to use iterator but I don't know how. Can somebody help? Thanks a bunch.

```
from numbers import Number

a = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]


def trav(root,s):
    if isinstance(root,Number):
        print(str(root) + " -> " + s)
    else:
        s = s + "0"
        trav(root[0],s)
        s = s[:-1]

        s = s + "1"
        trav(root[1],s)
        s = s[:-1]

s = ""
trav(a,s)
```

Comment: `s = s + "0"` would be neater as `s += "0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just...

```
def trav(root, s=""):
```

and then you can omit your `s = ""` line and call it as `trav(a)`? Also if you were willing to just inline a thing or two, you could do less slicing:

```
from numbers import Number

a = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]


def trav(root, s=""):
    if isinstance(root, Number):
        print("%s -> %s" % (root, s))
    else:
        trav(root[0], s + "0")
        trav(root[1], s + "1")

trav(a)
```

Note that none of this has anything to do with iterators; I'm not sure what you were thinking of there. `s` here acts as an *accumulator* argument; perhaps that's the term you were thinking of?